# fabricjs : prevent from dropping objects on each other

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to use fabricjs!
please see this picture :
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WseL1.jpg)
I want objects positioned beside of each other, but user can drop them on each other!
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbgcJ.jpg)
How can I solve this?

Comment: just for update...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think your question might be a duplicate of this one: [Prevent collision or intersection of canvas objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21435555/3345375)